# Select Particular Date using Python Selenium (Rollover dates)

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, selenium

All,

We are trying to automate the date picking process  **for reference** [Click here](https://reentryvisa.inis.gov.ie/website/INISOA/IOA.nsf/AppointmentSelection?OpenForm)! . Please refer date of birth  and Appointment date fields. The way we select date is is different. I am not able to get any idea about selecting the dates for both the fields. Could you please help me?

I have tried my best and it's working with below code except date fields

Python version : 2.7
Selenium 3.8.0
Chrome : 48X

```
    import selenium
    import sys
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    #profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    #profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('https://reentryvisa.inis.gov.ie/website/INISOA/IOA.nsf/AppointmentSelection?OpenForm');

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.find_element_by_id('btCom').click()

    username = driver.find_element_by_id('GivenName')
    username.send_keys("First name here ")

    username = driver.find_element_by_id('Surname')
    username.send_keys("Surname here")

    username = driver.find_element_by_id('DOB')
    username.click()            
 ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(username).click().send_keys('01/01/2011').perform()

    username = driver.find_element_by_id('Appdate')
    username.send_keys("12345")
```

I tried seeing the html for id names etc but I dint find anything specific to year date or month. All I got was below code

```
    <script src="/website/INISOA/IOA.nsf/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="/website/INISOA/IOA.nsf/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" for="DOB">* Date    of Birth:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group date dobdate">

    <input name="DOB" value="" id="DOB" class="form-control readonlywhite"  placeholder="Date of birth" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Please help me show away to select  the dates in both the fields (Date of birth and Appointment date)

Answer (score 0):

For the date of birth:

```
dob = driver.find_element_by_id('DOB')    
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", dob, '01/01/2011')
```

For appointment date:

```
appdate = driver.find_element_by_id('Appdate')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", appdate, '12/12/2017')
```

Comment: The set date disappeared after the window is closed. How to preserve the set value. Please help.

Comment: Which window are you referring to?

Comment: Did you try it without calling `.click` on the elements?

Comment: Yes, without .click.

Answer (score 0):

html for date/month/year popup is not under 'DOB input'. you can select the  popups using below selectors

```
datePopup = driver.find_element_by_class('datepicker-days')
monthPopup = driver.find_element_by_class('datepicker-month')
yearPopup = driver.find_element_by_class('datepicker-years')
```

Comment: like this? yearPopup = driver.find_element_by_class('datepicker-years')
yearPopup.send_keys("2011") and then month and date?

Comment: datepicker-years is not found error as well. I dint find datepicker-years in html