# Filling date field with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, selenium-webdriver-python

I am trying to fill out a registration form using Selenium for practice as I am beginning to familiarize myself with this library.

It is the registration form on this website: https://www.fast2sms.com/

### What I am currently trying

I start with this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.fast2sms.com/")
```

Over there, I click on the signup button with the `data-target` attribute set to `"#signupM"` using a css selector for the same:

```py
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-target="#signupM"]').click()
```

I then set up some dummy values for the fields:

```py
from phone_gen import PhoneNumber

name = "John Doe"
dob = "02-01-1990"
phone_number = PhoneNumber("India").get_number().replace("+91", "")
email_address = f"{phone_number}@mailinator.com"
```

I wait for the name field, and fill it:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

name_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="signup_name"]')))
name_field.send_keys(name)
```

Then phone number and email address:

```py
phone_number_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="signup_mobile"]')
phone_number_field.send_keys(phone_number)

email_addr_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="signup_email"]')
email_addr_field.send_keys(email_address)
```

Everything up until here works fine, exactly as expected, but when I try to fill in the Date of Birth field, I face issues:

```py
dob_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="signup_dob"]')
dob_field.send_keys(dob)
```

### Issues I face

1. Date of birth field is not filled.
2. It throws an error, `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`
3. I am unable to submit the form with date of birth not filled.

### Ways I have tried to debug

1. Rechecked the CSS Selector
2. Waited for the data-of-birth field to be interactable using WebDriverWait
3. Instead of filling in the text, I tried interacting with the popup that shows up when I click the field (I think I have to do this, but don't know how.)

### Questions which may seem like duplicates but are not:

[Select Particular Date using Python Selenium (Rollover dates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694455/select-particular-date-using-python-selenium-rollover-dates)

[Using Selenium on calendar date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520708/using-selenium-on-calendar-date-picker)

[Interacting with pop-up boxes using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789023/interacting-with-pop-up-boxes-using-selenium-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get why it may not be working. The website is using a particular javascript library called [datedropper](https://felixg.io/products/datedropper-javascript). Thus the input element for the date is in the readonly format.

I think you can resolve it by doing:

```
js_code = "document.querySelector('input[name=signup_dob]').value =" 
driver.execute_script(js_code + your_date)
```

Not quite sure the js code is gonna work. It might need some editing.

Comment: You seem to be right. But what exactly do I need to execute with driver.execute_script to set the date? I don't know JavaScript very well... :(

Comment: did not work, got this exception selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: window.querySelector is not a function

Comment: Yeah sorry. I'm testing it now. It should have been document, my bad :)

Comment: It still not working for me when I pass this `dob = "02-01-1990"`, it fills `-1989` in the input field. Certainly there's no error cause it fills something but it fills `-1989` any idea why ?

Comment: Unfortunately by passing your date in the console on the website I could not replicate your problem:

`document.querySelector('input[name=signup_dob]').value = '02-01-1990'`
 displays correctly 
`"02-01-1990"`

Can you share the relevant bit of code?